# filtering on pgrep to limit the result

Tags: debian, wine

I have an application running under WINE. However I need a way to get the processid (as part of a monitoring script).

On my old server (Debian) I simply did:

```
pgrep -f /home/user/directory/AppName.exe
```

However, on my new server (newer version of Debian) when I run this I get two results.

Looking at `ps aux | grep AppName.exe` I can see there are two results.

One is:

```
/bin/sh -e /usr/bin/wine /home/user/directory/AppName.exe
```

And the other is the same as above:

```
/home/user/directory/AppName.exe
```

What is the best way of filtering out the first one, so I am just left with the ProcessID of the one I want?

Comment: Just drop the `-f` option: `pgrep AppName.exe`

Comment: cheers, but when I do that it doesn't match either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not the best way to do it, but I have found found that if I use:

```
pgrep -fn /home/user/directory/AppName.exe
```

It gives me the correct one.

I tried using the `-x` option (exact match), but for some reason that didn't work.